# How do I lock screen on Live Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, lock-screen

I'm running Live Ubuntu 12.04. I don't see the 'Lock screen' button under the top right gear button. The shortcut Ctrl + Alt + L doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - you can't. Ubuntu Live Session User does not have password. If user does not have password, locking screen is meaningless.

However, you CAN create new user, and give him a new password. I believe, if you log in as this newly created user, you should be able to lock screen.

Comment: BTW, 14.04 will allow the user to lock screen with a keyboard shortcut: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/unity-lockscreen-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I'm already logged in under a password-ed user and not be able to lock the screen as described in the question.